# List of possible combinations for a logical expression

Tags: algorithms, combinations

I'm building a query builder GUI to build complex expressions. I wish to check if the expression may result in an ambiguity.

**Ex.** if the user's input is: `A or B and C or D` then I wish to show him the following ambiguities:

```
(A or B) and (C or D)
A or (B and C) or D
A or (B and (C or D))
((A or B) and C) or D
```

The operands count can reach 15-20 occasionally. Is this achievable? If yes, what is the best approach?

Comment: I think this count will grow too quickly as the count of operands grows. So even if achievable, I don't think it will look nice in an UI.

Comment: See also Catalan numbers.

Comment: @peter.petrov If its not possible to display all the combinations, at least is there way to tell the existence of ambiguity in an expression?

Comment: Well, if you use more than one operator (e.g. not all ANDs, or not all ORs), then there's always an ambiguity, right?

Comment: @DhiwaTdG You could try constructing a grammar for all possibly valid input, then a more restricted grammar for well-formed input. If the user's input is parsed by the first grammar but not the second, it's ambiguous. I'm assuming the user is allowed to input unambiguous expressions with parentheses, i.e. `(A and B) or C`

Comment: @peter.petrov You are right but until the user has placed parentheses wherever necessary, the expression will not be ambiguous. Ex: (A or B) and (C or D)

Comment: @DylanSp Yes, the user is allowed to input unambiguous expressions with parentheses. I couldn't understand your construction of grammar concept. Will you be able to demonstrate with a simple example for 3 operands?